# How do i remove this highlight script in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this stream script online. It uses jQuery and PHP to load more more comments when you click a div. But thats not what i need to know. It came preloaded with this feature where when your mouse is over the body of the comment (post_container) it gets highlighted. I cant read JS/ jQuery.. So can someone tell me where is is so i can remove it? It would really help :)

Heres the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>stream</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #posts-container            { width:400px; border:1px solid #ccc;  color: #62D7D7;  }
        .post                       { padding:5px 10px 5px 100px; min-height:65px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; background:url(dwloadmore.) 5px 5px no-repeat; cursor:pointer;  }
        .post:hover                 { background-color:lightblue; }
        a.post-title                { font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; }
        a.post-title:hover          { text-decoration:underline; color:#900; }
        a.post-more                 { color:#900; }
        p.item-content              { font-size:10px; line-height:17px; paddin color: #62D7D7;g-bottom:0; }
        #load-more                  {
    background-color:#eee;
    color:#999;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
        #load-more:hover            { color:#666; }
        .activate                   { background:url(loadmorespinner.gif) 140px 9px no-repeat #eee; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //when the DOM is ready
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //settings on top
            var domain = 'http://davidwalsh.name/';
            var initialPosts = <?php echo get_posts(0,$_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>;
            //function that creates posts
            var postHandler = function(postsJSON) {
                $.each(postsJSON,function(i,post) {
                    //post url
                    var postURL = '' + domain + post.name;
                    var id = 'post-' + post.ID;
                    //create the HTML
                    $('<div></div>')
                    .addClass('post')
                    .attr('id',id)
                    //generate the HTML
                    .html('<a href="' + postURL + '" class="post-title">' + post.username + '</a><p class="item-content">' + post.item_content + '<br /><a href="' + postURL + '" class="post-more">Read more...</a></p>')
                    .click(function() {
                        window.location = postURL;
                    })
                    //inject into the container
                    .appendTo($('#posts'))
                    .hide()
                    .slideDown(250,function() {
                        if(i == 0) {
                            $.scrollTo($('div#' + id));
                        }
                    });
                }); 
            };
            //place the initial posts in the page
            postHandler(initialPosts);
            //first, take care of the "load more"
            //when someone clicks on the "load more" DIV
            var start = <?php echo $_SESSION['posts_start']; ?>;
            var desiredPosts = <?php echo $number_of_posts; ?>;
            var loadMore = $('#load-more');
            //load event / ajax
            loadMore.click(function(){
                //add the activate class and change the message
                loadMore.addClass('activate').text('Loading...');
                //begin the ajax attempt
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'jquery-version.php',
                    data: {
                        'start': start,
                        'desiredPosts': desiredPosts
                    },
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(responseJSON) {
                        //reset the message
                        loadMore.text('Load More');
                        //increment the current status
                        start += desiredPosts;
                        //add in the new posts
                        postHandler(responseJSON);
                    },
                    //failure class
                    error: function() {
                        //reset the message
                        loadMore.text('Oops! Try Again.');
                    },
                    //complete event
                    complete: function() {
                        //remove the spinner
                        loadMore.removeClass('activate');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: SO is not crowd-sourced coding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the CSS line:

```
.post:hover { background-color:lightblue; }
```

**EDIT:**
You probably want to remove this too:

```
a.post-title:hover { text-decoration:underline; color:#900; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is occurring in the following area:

```
.post:hover                 { background-color:lightblue; }
```

you can remove the hover color by either:

- Removing the `.post:hover` line entirely.
- Removing `background-color` property inside of `.post:hover`: (`background-color:lightblue;`)

Here is a link if you want to learn a bit more about CSS:

[Intro to CSS - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp)